# What is the need for so many theories of acids and bases?

Tags: acid-base, terminology, history-of-chemistry

What is the need for the  Brønsted-Lowry theory and the Lewis theory of acids and bases?Is there any problem with the Arrhenius theory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First came the **Arrhenius theory**. It defines an acid as a species that **dissociates to produce $\ce{H+}$** in solution, and a base as a species that **dissociates to produce $\ce{OH-}$** in solution. (Examples: $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{NaOH}$)

Next came the **Brønsted-Lowry theory**, which expands the notion of acid and base. It **defines** an **acid as a species** that **loses $\ce{H+}$ in a reaction**, and a **base** as a species that **gains $\ce{H+}$ in a reaction**. All Arrhenius acids and bases are Brønsted-Lowry acids and bases; hence the Brønsted-Lowry theory generalizes the concepts of Arrhenius acids and bases and allows the application of these concepts to a larger range of species. (Examples of "new" acids and bases under this theory: $\ce{NH4+}$, $\ce{CH3COO-}$)

Finally came the **Lewis theory**, which further expands the notion of acid and base. It **defines an acid as a species** that **accepts an electron pair**, and a **base as a species that donates an electron pair**. All Brønsted-Lowry acids and bases are Lewis acids and bases; hence the Lewis theory generalizes the concepts of Brønsted-Lowry acids and bases and allows the application of these concepts to a larger range of species. (Examples of "new" acids and bases under this theory: $\ce{Li+}$, $\ce{CO}$)

---

**Remark:** Hopefully the repetition and structure within my answer has been suggestive. The benefits of generalization are obvious: the theory can explain more, and more things can be explained; this is the natural progression of science.

Comment: Nice post, but I'd point out that by working up from the Arrhenius theory through the Brønsted-Lowry theory to the Lewis theory one develops a good knowledge of the subtleties of chemistry. Like in math you don't need a  10 pound theorem to prove a two pound problem.

Comment: Shouldn't "solution" in Arrhenius theory be qualified by "aqueous" or is it that the dissociation can take place in any solution?

Comment: @MrAP, yes, an aqueous solution is implied.